# I will like to know how to measure displacement using a piezooectric transducer

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, piezoelectric

I am attaching a piezoelectric patch at a point of a moving object, I will like help to know how to convert the output voltage responseI get drom an oscilloscope to displacement values in mm.
I will be very gratedul to get a response.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I want to convert voltage response to displacement in mm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Piezos detect *force*, not *displacement*, so an indirect approach is needed, as follows.

For an object that is set into motion, a piezo transducer attached to it will produce an output voltage proportional to the *acceleration* of that object. This is because the transducer has mass, and F = mA. The *time integral* of the acceleration will then yield the *velocity* of that object.

This technique of deducing *velocities* from *forces* using piezos with calibrated test masses attached to them is very common and furnishes the basis for the design of modern solid-state *accelerometers*.

Integrating velocity over time will yield *displacement* too, but for best accuracy, extremely precise time measurements and force measurements are needed to feed the integration engine.

Stable, precision accelerometers combined with high-precision clocks form the basis in turn of *inertial navigation systems* as used in aircraft and ballistic missiles.

Comment: Thanks alot for your response. This transducers I am using are flat piezo strips like PVDF or MFC strips., not with any mass attached to the tips,  Will that still apply? I am using  these strips on a soft tissue on the body, , to measure the movement of the soft tissue as the body moves.

Comment: that may be difficult, but here are some ideas: in the world of amateur robotics, there are general purpose controller boards called *arduino, raspberry pi* , *and *beaglebone*. accelerometer devices are available for these and the arduino board takes the signals from them and can process them in dozens of useful ways. Suggest you look into this- a solution probably already exists for your application in that field. -Niels